# How can I make a directory always listening?

Tags: javascript, image, optimization, gulp, ecmascript-5

I use `gulp.js` to minify, compress, optimize my static files. Now I have a directory contains all users' avatars. When a user registers, my PHP code will generate an avatar for him and copy/paste it into that directory.

The size of an avatar is almost 20kb. I can call this task manually every time on that directory to reduce images (avatars) sizes:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('compress_avatars', () =>
    gulp.src('pure/img/avatars/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('product/img/avatars'))
);
```

It works as well and make the size of images almost 3kb. All fine. Now I want to know, how can I make it automatically *(real time listening)*? I mean, when an image added to this directory I need to reduce its size automatically *(without executing `gulp compress_avatars` every time by by hand)* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gulp.watch` instead `gulp.src` to check any change in this directory and compress your avatars files.

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('compress_avatars', () =>
  gulp.watch('pure/img/avatars/*', {ignoreInitial: false})
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('product/img/avatars'))
);
```

You must know that this task will not stop until you send a Ctrl-c (`SIGINT` signal), but if you close the terminal you will close the task!

Comment: Thank you, upvote. Just what exactly you mean by **" You must take care"**? Should I do any specific thing? Also will it full the Ram? Is using `.watch` a bad job?

Comment: No, this **"you must take care"** it's related to **"don't kill the job"**, **"don't close de console"**. This is a tiny task, you should run this task in background, and let it do all the job. Sorry about that warning haha.